# .htaccess Rewriting url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite the url with .htaccess file but it throws an error in some situations.
I've been trying to convert
`example.com/room.php` to `example.com/room` and it works, but also, to convert
`example.com/room.php?room=5` to `example.com/room/5`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Remove the trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Redirect page.php to page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

# Internally redirect page to page.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^room/(.*?)$ /room.php?room=$1 [L,NC]
```

And it successfully converts `room.php` to `room`, buy when I try to visit `room/5` it gives me `500 Internal Server Error`. I've tried everything but still don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I think you have extra extension _.php_ in this condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Remove the trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Redirect page.php to page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^room/([^/]+)/?$ room.php?room=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

# Internally redirect page to page.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```